# Delete function is not working to delete a row in the table in php ajax

Tags: php, ajax, row

I want to delete a row by clicking the delete button.

I have done with editing the data in the row.i want to delete the data in the row.And the delete operation is not working.

```
  db.php
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "View_ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function(dataResult){
            $('#table').html(dataResult); 
        }
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { 
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete_ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data:{
                id: $(this).attr("data-id")
            },
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>



delete_ajax.php
    <?php
        include "php/dbConfig.php";
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `task` WHERE id=$id";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200));
        } 
        else {
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>

view_ajax.php
<td><input type='button' onclick="delete_user('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');"
            data-id="<?=$row['id'];?>"
            data-firstname="<?=$row['firstname'];?>"
            data-lastname="<?=$row['lastname'];?>"
            data-username="<?=$row['username'];?>"
            data-password="<?=$row['password'];?>"
            "></button></td>

by clicking the delete button i want the entire row to be deleted.
```

The delete function is not working.Kindly help me with it.

Comment: You may need to show us the code you have in delete_ajax.php and perhaps explain the specific problem if you can.

Comment: i have added the code i tried.please just check it out.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { ` i can't see html tag with "delete" class...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `delete` class in html tag

```
<input class="delete" type='button' ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Js can't find delete of css class ,anywhere add to element

```
<element class='delete' >remove </element>
```